# complie and using opencv on gpu for image processing with python

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, gpu

I want to do some image processing with python using Opencv library.
actually i want to read a lot of images from an object storage and do some image processing on each image and want to do it as fast as possible.
I want to compile and use Opencv on gpu instead of cpu to gain most speed.

is there anyway to using gpu for this purpose?
(I know that it is possible with c++)
is there GPU module in OpenCV for python? I didn't any wrapper for python.

Answer (score 0):

Yes opencv does have gpu module in python 3. You can visit https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/gpu/doc/introduction.html
for more information. There are plenty of examples.

There is an example of gpu acceleration https://answers.opencv.org/question/203403/opencv-gpu-accelerated-using-python/

Comment: thank you. but in your first link it isn't anything about python.

from your second link, i saw that in first example:

`test(img, N, "Mat")`
and
`test(cv2.UMat(img), N, "UMat")`

is it ok just using cv2.UMat to work with gpu?  isn't need to be compiled opencv on gpu?